# Is it possible to have public posts in a non-public custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm working on a theme that incorporates a cpt to manage the various team members of an organization. The team gets displayed on page with an image, name, function etc., in addition specific people are supposed to get an individual page each with more elaborate information.

The basics of this work fine. The problem I'm running into is how to make sure that only proper posts, i.e. the ones with more than a picture and a name, are reachable from the frontend.

So far I could only think of two ways to achieve this and neither looks all that great to me:

1. A non-public cpt and regular pages that can display team members via page-template.
   This works fine if only a few people get the elaborate treatment, but is essentially double entry bookkeeping and clutters the regular page overview.
2. A public cpt and doing my outmost to keep the "wrong" posts hidden.
   This has backfired on me in the past with effectively useless pages showing up in a Google query because a plug-in added them to the sitemap.

Is there another method that achieves what I want but less error prone and without a lot of administrative overhead?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You only want to  display a post *if* it has more than 1 image in it's content and a post title?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Not quite. I have a custom post type with a bunch of posts, some of these(A) have more content than the others(B). (A) should be reachable with a permalink like /team/john-smith/, (B) shouldn't. Because (B) would look incomplete without all the extra content (A) has. Does that help?

Comment: I mean... I get you don't want to display incomplete content by why is it incomplete? Is (A) and (B) the same post type? You can make a post type that doesn't get index which sorta makes it private, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes it's the same post type, that's what causes the whole dilemma. (B) isn't incomplete, it just _looks_ that way because it's less information. A name and a picture as opposed to a name, picture, vita and more.

Comment: So, it's complete data that *is* being published but you *don't* want it accessible by permalink... So why publish it at all? When saving the post why not check for some kind of specific content needed to be published and if it doesn't have this information, change the `post-status` to Draft.

Comment: Because it is viewable on an archive-like page. Though I guess setting it to private for the ones that shouldn't be viewable on individual pages but show up in the archives would work.